# Ubuntu 13.10 freezing when dragging window to expand full size from half screen?

Tags: window-management

Lately I've found a greater need to have one window/program on the left half and another on the right, however when dragging to expand one window full screen it often results in a crash where the mouse moves (stuck on the hand symbol), but is unresponsive to clicks.

Luckily the keyboard still responds to some commands and I've been able to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to reboot from there, or use the REISUB thing.

I would happily use the top left maximise button, but this usually results in the desired window locking to centre but still half sized. Also, dragging to maximise doesn't always result in a crash, sometimes it'll be the tenth time I do it, sometimes the first or second.

Any ideas what could be causing this ?

Or any way I can stop this happening (apart from not using the feature, obviously) ?